# Sum of premium by category to get the difference between two tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Desired result set

Assume we are migrating the tables from legacy system to new system and my scenario is to check the sum of premium group by category should be matching between legacy and new system

in the below attached sheet sum of premium for the category "First Party" in legacy is not matched with the CC table

so i want to find the mean of difference between sum and result should be come as

100, First Party

If no difference between two tables then populate as 0

Query:

sum of premium group by category

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `full join` to get the differences.  It does not bother with the groups that match.

It also assumes that you care about `loggeddate` as well as `category`.  If not, remove it from the query:

```
select loggeddate, category, l.premium as legacy_premium, cc.premium as cc_premium
from (select loggeddate, category, sum(premium) as premium
      from legacy
      group by loggeddate, category
     ) l full join
     (select loggeddate, category, sum(premium) as premium
      from cc
      group by loggeddate, category
     ) c
where l.premium <> c.premium or
      l.premium is null or
      c.premium is null;
 using (loggeddate, category);
```

If you really want the matches as well, just remove the `where` and add `l.premium - c.premium` to the `select`.  The differences seem more useful to me.